# Error initializing TesseractProcessor

Tags: c#, ocr

I have the following problem with Tesseract - I downloaded all neccessary files (at least I hope so) and here is how my super duper simple application looks like:

```
string sLocation = @"m:\Tesseract\tesseractdotnet_v301_r590\x86release_assemblies\data\";
string sLang = "eng";
TesseractProcessor processor = new TesseractProcessor();

if (processor.Init(sLocation, sLang,(int)eOcrEngineMode.OEM_DEFAULT))
{
     System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("OK");
}
else
{
     System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Failed");
}
```

It simply initializes Tesseract. However I get the following error message:

> *Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.*

If I changed the DLL to different tesseract then I got error which said:

> *Could not load file or assembly 'tesseract.dll' or one of its dependencies. The application has failed to start because its
>   side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application
>   event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800736B1)*

I changed my platform target to **x86** but it is not working anyways. I am using Visual Studio 2012. Can someone please help me with this problem? What am I doing wrong?

I have list of small pictures containing only numbers and few letters I want to decode and retrieve text from.

**EDIT**

OK I figured out that tesseractdotnet_v301_r590 works only with tessdata v 3.01 (not latest 3.02) and this was causing the problem. However how can I work with the latest data, when on tesseractdotnet they have only r590 version? Here is my download link.

https://code.google.com/p/tesseractdotnet/downloads/list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I figured out that tesseractdotnet_v301_r590 works only with tessdata v 3.01 (not latest 3.02) and this was causing the problem. However I have no idea how to make it work with 3.02 data files.

Here is the download link:
https://code.google.com/p/tesseractdotnet/downloads/list